# How to place limit values on the top and bottom of summation in a fraction

Tags: equations, symbols

I am trying to write the upper and lower limits on the summation symbol in this equation as

```
\[Average~accuracy =\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{6}{Accuracy_i}}{i}=94.45\%\]
```

or

```
$Average~accuracy =\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{6}{Accuracy_i}}{i}=94.45\%$
```

But both are printing the limits at the edges. Is there any way to print them at the top and bottom as we write them with pen and paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\text{Average accuracy} = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{6}{\text{Accuracy}_i}}{i}=94.45\%
\]

\[
\text{Average accuracy} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{6}{\text{Accuracy}_i}}{i}=94.45\%
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.